# Не добавляются строки в таблицу в проекте с несколькими контроллерами

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

В общем, решил я в учебных целях сделать проект с несколькими таблицами и несколькими контроллерами. И я задумал так, что для каждой таблицы у меня  будет по два контроллера- один для вставки строк, а другой  для вывода их на экран(В перспективе возможно добавление в эти вторые контроллеры методов  для редактирования и удаления строк .). И получилось так,  что первые две таблицы с четырьмя контроллерами я сделал и отладил именно так, как задумывал. Все работало отлично. А когда я пытаюсь вывести на  экран строки из третьей таблицы ,то у меня выскакивает такая ошибка:

System.NullReferenceException. Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
И  указывает эта ошибка на такую строку в представлении:

```
    @foreach (var b in ViewBag.Satellites)
```

Я сильно подозреваю, что это на самом деле потому, потому что у меня  самом деле никакие  строки в таблицу Satellite не добавились. Когда я пытался добавить строки в эту  таблицу  и нажимал" Добавить", то у меня выскакивала ошибка

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'SolarSystemContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database.
В одном видео на Youtube сказали, что это можно фиксировать вот такой строкой в Global.asax :

```
        Database.SetInitializer<SolarSystemContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SolarSystemContext>());
```

Один человек в комментарии под видео  написал ,что это не выход, потому что эта строка удаляет все строки в базе, и у меня так и получилось(Кстати говоря ,интересно, для чего вообще нужен этот  DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges?).
Потом я опять  инициализировал базу вот этой  строкой:

```
 Database.SetInitializer(new SolarSystemDbInitializer());
```

Теперь у меня при нажатии "Добавить" в представлении никакие ошибки не выскакивают,  но при попытке  вывести строки на экран происходит то ,что я уже рассказывал. Вот код модели Satellite:

```
 using System;

 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;

  namespace SolarSystemThree.Models
  {
    public class Satellite
    {



    public int SatelliteId { get; set; }

    public double? Volume { get; set; }

    public double? Weight { get; set; }
    public double? Diameter { get; set; }

    public decimal DistanceMain { get; set; }
    public double RotationMain { get; set; }
    public double? Rotation { get; set; }
    public string Affiliation { get; set; }
    public int? QuantitySatellites { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
 }
```

Вот код контроллера InsertSatellite

```
 using System;



  using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
      using SolarSystemThree.Models;

      namespace SolarSystemThree.Controllers
      {
        public class InsertSatelliteController : Controller
       {


    SolarSystemContext db = new SolarSystemContext();

    // GET: InsertPlanet
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult InsertToSatellite()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertToSatellite(Satellite satellite)
    {
        db.Satellites.Add(satellite);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
    public ActionResult Success()
    {
        return View();

    }
}
   }
```

А самое интересное знаете что? Я поставил точки останова напротив этих двух строк:

```
        db.Satellites.Add(satellite);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

И студия сказала мне про каждую из этих строк ,что" 0 ошибок ","0 предупреждений ","0 сообщений". Я хочу спросить: подход CodeFirst, который я использую,  имеет какие-то ограничения в количестве таблиц или контроллеров ,или я просто что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Чёт в приведенном коде нигде не видно, чтоб вы где-то передавали коллекцию спутников во `ViewBag`. Не потому ли возникают ошибка при попытке получить хоть что-то из `ViewBag.Satellites`?

Answer (score 1):

Bulson прав,получилось так, что я в  контроллере  HomeSatelliteController приравнял переменную IEnumerable satellites к  ViewBag.Planets, а не к  ViewBag.Satellites. У меня было так:

```
    public ActionResult IndexSatellite()
    {
        IEnumerable<Satellite> satellites = db.Satellites;
        ViewBag.Planets = satellites;
        return View();
    }
```

А надо было так:

```
    public ActionResult IndexSatellite()
    {
        IEnumerable<Satellite> satellites = db.Satellites;
        ViewBag.Satellites = satellites;
        return View();
    }
```